# Next cell when button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

Below the code. It currently just gives the first cell out and i don't know why it doesn't go to the next cell, when clicking on the button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 Dim notFirst As Boolean
 Dim rng As Range

 If notFirst Then
    If rng.Row = 104 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    End If
 Else
    Set rng = Range("A102")
    notFirst = True
 End If

 Range("C8").Value = rng.Value

End Sub
```

How it looks like:

https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-73e0c4-1584092523.png.html

https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-5cfb6a-1584092581.png.html

Comment: It makes perfect sense. It goes straight to your `Else` (since `notFirst` is `FALSE`). It then sets a range variable and set `notFirst` to `TRUE` and that's basically it. This will always return the value from `Range(Ä102")` from then then `ActiveSheet`. What are you actually expecting?

Comment: It just shows the first question in cell "A102" but the other questions below dont appear.

Comment: Improve your question with sample data and expected output so it's easier to help you out. Right now, you are overwriting a single cell > `C8` with a single value. You haven't mentioned ***other questions***, so I guess you should explain on that.

Comment: i added two pictures to show you my problem maybe know you can understand what i want. The button "Neue Frage" should get a new question everytime it got used. By clicking one time on the button it should be "Frage 1" then clickling on the button it should be "Frage 2" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
Public notFirst As Boolean
Public rng As Range

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 If notFirst Then
    If rng.Row = 104 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    End If
 Else
    Set rng = Range("A102")
    notFirst = True
 End If

 Range("C8").Value = rng.Value

End Sub
```

These `Public` variables make sure that when you click your button again the last assigned value is still present. Note that I would not nesecarily recommend the above code to do what it is you are doing.

Comment: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-c49be1-1584093740.png.html after the change it slides up do you know why?

Comment: @Dradoris, put the `Public` variables **above** all the subs in that module!

Comment: You can also use [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) variables if you do not want to make the variable accessible module/project wise.

Comment: @VincentG, yes that's also a possibility